# How to pass a variable defined within an on click to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass the variable `mySearchTitle` to a function in order to read `page: mySearchTitle`

```
   var mySearchTitle;
    $("#wikiResults li a").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      mySearchTitle = $(this).html().replace(/ /g,"_");
      console.log($(this).html().replace(/ /g,"_"));
      textWiki(mySearchTitle);
    });
  }
  function textWiki() {
    $.getJSON("https://"+ queryLang +".wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&prop=text&limit=1&callback=?", {
      page: mySearchTitle
```

But i get in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mySearchTitle is not defined
```

Comment: `function textWiki(mySearchTitle){}` ?

Comment: @guradio ok will try now

Comment: Pass it as the argument to your function.

Comment: great works. Thanks

Comment: @guradio Post your answer as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use variable in a function you need to pass it as an argument to the function

```
function textWiki(mySearchTitle){
         //use mySearchTitle as needed
}
```